# How do we find common word between two string?

Tags: python, string, algorithm, data-structures, trie

Suppose we have two strings, we need to find common words between those two strings.

```
str1 = "hit hop hat"
str2 = "hot has hit hop"

output = ["hit", "hop"]
```

I know we can use a just split the string and put words the set and take the intersection. My question is how can we optimize space? What if many strings have a common prefix?

Comment: There is no obvious reason to optimize anything, but if you wish you can implement a trie.

Comment: @zvone can you please explain how it will work? Like building trie of one sting and searching words from other string?

Comment: Yes, I guess that would be the way to go. But at which point that actually becomes faster than using sets is a big question. As for the space, if you have a file larger than available RAM as input, maybe then it would make sense.

Comment: @zone, yeah make sense, but I was thinking what if we make two tries for each sentence for in parallel and compare those tries? I don't know but how I will be comparing the two tries. Is there such a thing where we can compare two tries and find similarities?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to solve this question by creating a simplified trie from the smaller list of words, and subsequently searching it for a match for each of the words in the longer list:

```
def create_simplified_trie(words):
    trie = {}
    for word in words:
        curr = trie
        for c in word:
            if c not in curr:
                curr[c] = {}
            curr = curr[c]
        # Mark the end of a word
        curr['#'] = True  
    return trie

str1 = "hit hop hat"
str2 = "hot has hit hop"
words1 = str1.split()
words2 = str2.split()
# Ensure words1 is the smaller length list
if len(words1) > len(words2):
    words1, words2 = words2, words1

words1_trie = create_simplified_trie(words1)

output = []
for word in words2:
    curr = words1_trie
    found_prefix = True
    for c in word:
        if c not in curr:
            found_prefix = False
            break
        curr = curr[c]
    if found_prefix and '#' in curr:
        output.append(word)

print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
['hit', 'hop']
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am still new to tries. Would it make sense to make two tries for two sentences and compare for the similarity between these tries?

Comment: I think you only need to create a trie for one of the sentences and search to see if the words in the other sentence occur in it (i.e., the word occurs in both sentences).

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would use sets of words and their intersections as in the following :

```
>>> str1 = "hit hop hat"
>>> str2 = "hot has hit hop"

>>> set_of_words1=set( str1.split() )
>>> set_of_words2=set( str2.split() )

>>> set_of_words1 & set_of_words2
{'hop', 'hit'}
```